# Why does my Powershell session sometimes refuse to run external commandline programs?

Tags: powershell

I'm having a weird problem where, when doing a lot of playing in the Powershell commandline, at some point it will stop executing any commandline application like `cmd.exe` or `more.com`, but will continue to execute Powershell functions and such. I can open up a new Powershell window

### The situation

- I'm using [Powershell Community Extensions](http://pscx.codeplex.com/)
- I have a [Powershell profile](http://younix.us/cgit/cgit.cgi/dhd.git/tree/hbase/Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1)
- I seem to encounter this when I'm trying to debug [a script I'm writing](http://pastebin.com/WqxyXQFU) (more on that later)

### The problem by example

Normally I should be able to run ping and see normal output like this:

```
PS> ping google.com
Pinging google.com [74.125.227.78] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 74.125.227.78: bytes=32 time=30ms TTL=49 
Reply from 74.125.227.78: bytes=32 time=38ms TTL=49 
Reply from 74.125.227.78: bytes=32 time=31ms TTL=49 
Reply from 74.125.227.78: bytes=32 time=32ms TTL=49 

Ping statistics for 74.125.227.78:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 30ms, Maximum = 38ms, Average = 32ms 
PS>
```

However, when I'm experiencing this problem, the PS prompt just returns immediately:

```
PS> ping google.com
PS>
```

I can verify in Task Manager that ping is not running during this time. Furthermore, for programs which should modify files on the filesystem (like `takeown.exe` or GnuWin32's `wget.exe`), the modifications do not occur. As far as I can tell, the command does not run at all.

This happens with every non-Powershell commandline app I can think of (`more.com`, GnuWin32's `less.exe`, `ping.exe`, `cmd.exe`, `python.exe` from the official Python distribution, StrawberryPerl's `perl.exe`, etc).

I can still run any Powershell function, cmdlet, or alias. Furthermore, I can run non-commandline apps like `notepad.exe`.

### The (possible) culprit: my script

I have been trying to write a PS script over the last few days, when this problem started to crop up. It's too long to paste here (400 lines at the moment), but I've [uploaded it to pastebin](http://pastebin.com/WqxyXQFU) if you want to see it. (Currently not working very well.)

Right now I'm dealing with some permissions problems in the WinPE-AddExplorer function in that script, so a lot of the time I'm Ctrl-C'ing while that function is running... could something in there be causing the problem?

Comment: Did you get this problem solved?

Comment: Sadly, no. I'm afraid I've moved on from that job so I don't have the code or the machine any more. If you manage to find an answer anyway, though, I'd be very interested to read it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this exact problem. I'm guessing you're using Powershell V2. Please see this bug report (https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/Feedback/Details/665809). Supposedly fixed in Powershell v3. (I have not seen this problem in v4 using the same script that does not work in v2)

The workaround is to put "[GC]::Collect()" in your loop that writes to the console.

Comment: OMG no way, I can't believe someone came back to this after all this time. I no longer have access to the machine in question, so I can't test this as a fix, but since it was precisely the behavior I was seeing I'm gonna go ahead and mark it as the answer. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for the upvote! Ever since I read this XKCD, I have tried to contribute to the good karma of the coding universe:
http://xkcd.com/979/

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few thoughts:

1. Try running PowerShell with -NoProfile. Import the PSCX module and run your script
2. Try running PowerShell without the PSCX module (adjust your profile script to NOT import, if necessary), then try running your script
3. Try not to use 3rd party modules in general

On another note, I had a look through your script, and nothing jumps out at me that would be permanently adjusting your PowerShell session. To debug this issue, try to think of any permanent, environmental changes that your profile (or your script) might be making. The developers of PSCX may or may not have code that makes permanent adjustments to your PowerShell environment also.

Use traditional troubleshooting techniques to help zero in on what area (your script, PSCX, or your profile) is causing you this problem.